# How to edit multiple records in mysql using sql update

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sql-update, record

Version MySQL: 5.5.28
phpMyAdmin - 2.11.11.3

I have multiple records of the type: name_test/, name_test/etc, name_test/etc/etc name_test/etc/etc/etc/etc and I want them to be like Top/name_test/, Top/name_test/etc, Top/name_test/etc/etc/, Top/name_test/etc/etc/etc/etc .

90% of them have already changed so we need to SELECT only those record that start with "name_test/"
problem is a problem is a bit more complicated, i you have to change some 4 million filds.

```
**table exemple1**

**column1**             **column2**                 **column3**
name_test1              name_test2/etc              name_test3
Top/etc/etc/            Top/name_test2/etc/etc/     name_test/etc/etc/
name_test               Top/name_test/etc/
name_test               #name_test/etc/etc/etc/#
name_test               #name_test/etc/etc/#
name_test2              #name_test/etc/#
name_test5              #name_test/#
name_test/etc
```

I have other tables with language like this:

```
**table exemple2**

**column1**             **column2**                 **column3**
name_test1              italian:name_test2/etc              name_test3
Top/etc/etc/            english:Top/name_test2/etc/etc/     name_test/etc/etc/
name_test               Bulgarian:Top/name_test/etc/
name_test               Danish:#name_test/etc/etc/etc/#
name_test               Korean:#name_test/etc/etc/#
name_test2              Russian:#name_test/etc/#
name_test5              etc:#name_test/#
name_test/etc
```

Note: only this #filds# must be modified in the example

other records that start otherwise not be modified
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you elaborate more on your question ?

Comment: Would you paste a single record example before and after the update operation. What is the criteria that the record to be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
UPDATE table
SET column2 = concat('Top/', column2)
WHERE column2 LIKE 'name_test/%'
```

Comment: I added more details, do you have any idea?

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your update. One small change is also to use `LIKE 'name_test/%'` so it will not touch name_test2 records

Comment: Best regards, you save my life :)

Comment: btw, it is considered good idea here to accept or vote up helpful answers

Comment: for the moment I can not vote enough points: Vote Up requires 15 reputation
(click on this box to dismiss) when i have points, you surely vote

Comment: UPDATE table
SET column2 = concat('Top/', column2)
WHERE column2 LIKE '%:name_test/%' may be a solution?

Comment: No, for records like Russian:name_test/etc/ this would not work as it will add Top/ in front. For these, you should probably write small perl script that is using DBI to edit your data in more complicated ways than SQL can allow.